QuantLib Python: Calculate ZSpread
I am trying to use quantlib-python to calculate the z-spread of a fixed rate US corporate bond using a zero curve from swap rates provided.
Here is the provided curve with dates, zeroes and discount factors.
{'date': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-16 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-23 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-02-18 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-04-16 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-06-17 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-09-16 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-12-16 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-03-17 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-06-16 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2021-09-15 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2021-12-15 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2022-01-18 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2022-07-18 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2023-01-17 00:00:00'),
  15: Timestamp('2023-07-17 00:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2024-01-16 00:00:00'),
  17: Timestamp('2024-07-16 00:00:00')},
 'rate': {0: 1.5730452119529836,
  1: 1.5730452119025795,
  2: 1.7279111508652356,
  3: 1.7913216016440803,
  4: 1.8674426107576636,
  5: 1.8294634933805565,
  6: 1.7852819839324852,
  7: 1.740006104698466,
  8: 1.707636622424058,
  9: 1.6797318490155533,
  10: 1.6591129486236866,
  11: 1.6405257638334003,
  12: 1.6361045982494105,
  13: 1.622831403886238,
  14: 1.6095006947274282,
  15: 1.6096802648009056,
  16: 1.6098318250594712,
  17: 1.6176504630707633},
 'df': {0: 1.0,
  1: 0.9996953731036011,
  2: 0.9984718446661575,
  3: 0.9970321675811668,
  4: 0.9953638349734837,
  5: 0.9923904015148071,
  6: 0.988220850440741,
  7: 0.9842443665336315,
  8: 0.9803113137907096,
  9: 0.9765817360374307,
  10: 0.9728825409783471,
  11: 0.9692140750801099,
  12: 0.9678487049444453,
  13: 0.9603121753425592,
  14: 0.9530038843473384,
  15: 0.9453899093059526,
  16: 0.9378779089627198,
  17: 0.930064389274982}}

Here is the code I have after I load the curve as df.
df.columns = ['date', 'rate', 'df']
day_count = ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.USA)
dates = [ql.Date(d.day, d.month, d.year) for d in df['date']]
crv = ql.ZeroCurve(dates, df['rate'], day_count, ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond))

crv = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(crv)

start = ql.Date(1,11,2013)
maturity = ql.Date(1,11,2023)
schedule = ql.MakeSchedule(start, maturity, ql.Period('6M'))
settlement_days = 2


interest = ql.FixedRateLeg(schedule, day_count, [100.], [0.0345])
bond = ql.Bond(settlement_days, ql.TARGET(), start, interest)

today = ql.Date(14, 1, 2020)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

ql.BondFunctions.zSpread(bond,86.22,crv,day_count,ql.Compounded,ql.Annual)

I am receiving the error TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'BondFunctions_zSpread and am not sure which input is causing the error or how to resolve.

You can see the interface of zSpread declared at https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/v1.33/SWIG/bondfunctions.i#L146.
It takes a shared_ptr to term structure (which in Python means a term structure), not a handle.  If you avoid the crv = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(crv), it should work.

If I comment out crv = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(crv), I then get RuntimeError: positive compound factor required.

My error arises since rates were passed as percentages (say 1.5) rather than decimals 0.015.

The error message suggests that there may be an issue with the number or type of arguments you are passing to the BondFunctions.zSpread function.
The BondFunctions.zSpread function typically takes the following arguments:
Bond object the bond for which you want to calculate the z-spread.
cleanPrice the clean price of the bond.
curve the yield term structure handle.
dayCount the day count convention.
compounding the compounding frequency.
frequency: the coupon frequency.
Make sure that you are passing the correct arguments in the correct order.
